# Theta asymptotic for $\binom{2m}{m}$

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

Show that 
$\binom{2m}{m} = \Theta\left(\frac{2^{2m}}{\sqrt{m}}\right)$ without using Stirling's approximation.

Comment: It would be neat if we could find a combinatorial proof that $m\binom{2m}{m}^2 \leq 2^{4m}$. Clearly, $\binom{2m}{m}^2$ counts a particular class of subsets of size $2m$ in the set of size $4m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full answer, but some suggestions: the numerator can be rewritten as 
$$
(2m)!=1 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2m=1\cdot 3\cdot \ldots \cdot (2m-1)(2 \cdot  4 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2m=(2-1) \cdot (4-1)\cdot \ldots \cdot (2m-1)
(2 \cdot 1) \cdot (2 \cdot 2) \cdot (2 \cdot 3) \cdot \ldots \cdot 2m \leq 2^{m} m! \cdot 2^m m!=2^{2m} (m!)^2
$$
Then you remain with $2^{2m}$ as an upper bound. Can you handle from here?